# Capitalize first character of a word in a string

Tags: python, if-statement, join, split

How is one of the following versions different from the other?

1. The following code returns the first letter of a word from string capitalize:

   ```
   s = ' '.join(i[0].upper() + i[1:] for i in s.split())
   ```
2. The following code prints only the last word with every character separated by space:

   ```
   for i in s.split():
       s=' '.join(i[0].upper()+i[1:]
       print s
   ```

Comment: You've answered your own question, haven't you?

Comment: to capitalize a word use `str.capitalize`: `s = ' '.join(i.capitalize() for i in s.split())`

Comment: @Daniel or simply `title` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in s.split():`
```

At this point `i` is a word.

```
s = ' '.join(i[0].upper() + i[1:])
```

Here, `i[0]` is the first character of the string, and `i[1:]` is the rest of the string.  This, therefore, is a shortcut for `s = ' '.join(capitalized_s)`.  The `str.join()` method takes as its argument a single iterable.  In this case, the iterable is a string, but that makes no difference.  For something such as `' '.join("this")`, `str.join()` iterates through each element of the iterable (each character of the string) and puts a space between each one.  Result: `t h i s`  There is, however, an easier way to do what you want: `s = s.title()`

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand what is different if i put the for statement at the beginning or at the end. Should't they output the same result ?

Comment: In the first example, you are putting the whole string into the `' '.join` method, but in the second example, you are using `' '.join` on each word.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness and for people who find this question via a search engine, the proper way to capitalize the first letter of every word in a string is to use the `title` method.

```
>>> capitalize_me = 'hello stackoverlow, how are you?'
>>> capitalize_me.title()
'Hello Stackoverlow, How Are You?'
```